# How can I implement bi-directional data binding with url parameters?

Tags: angularjs

I am building a search form for an AngularJS app. I want users to be able to **create a persistent bookmark** representing their current search parameters.

[Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights) does this really well. Whenever you change one of the search inputs, the URL is updated.

NOTE: I am looking to see if this can be accomplished without the using the ngRoute module.

I have all the search parameter data encapsulated in a `SearchParametersService`. And could easily create a function to serialize/deserialize my model to/from a url, but I am wondering where this logic should live inside an AngularJS app?

Should I create a directive? If so, should I just attach it to the body tag? Or should this go somewhere else?

In case it is helpful, here's the `SearchParametersService` I am using.

```
app.factory("SearchParametersService", function (SearchOptions) {
    return {
        searchType: _.first(SearchOptions.searchTypes),
        cabinClass: _.first(SearchOptions.cabinClasses),
        fareTypes: _.filter(SearchOptions.fareTypes, function (option) {
            return ~_.indexOf(["NEG", "PUB"], option.value);
        }),
        numberOfStops: 1,
        adults: 1,
        children: 0,
        outboundOrigin: null,
        outboundDestination: null,
        outboundDate: null,
        inboundOrigin: null,
        inboundDestination: null,
        inboundDate: null,
        carriers: []
    };
})
```

Comment: Is SearchParametersService actually is a angular service?

Comment: Yes. I have added that code to my question.

Comment: Ok so you want to have the url updated when the search parameters are changed so users can bookmark the page, but then you don't want to use angular routes? But if you look at Google Flight, they are using some kind of route service.

Comment: How can you tell they're using a route service?

Comment: Usage of # in the url. It was used to go to a certain anchor in the same html document, thus the page does not reload when you change it. Angular route service use the same "hack" to manage routes and routeParams.

Comment: I am very familiar with angular routes, but something tells me this is a bit different. I may be totally wrong though. Anyhow, I would love to see whether there is a way to do this without using routes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37211/discussion-between-jlareau-and-jessegavin)